# Take the container and text field over the keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a new social media application. I have a comment system. When user add comment, press the comments button and after press button I am showing the showModalBottomSheet. There is one text field and one container in Showmodalbottomsheet. I was able to get the showmodalbottomsheet on the keyboard with only text field before, but when I added the container to show comments later, I can't get it over the keyboard. Anyone can help me ?

```
  Widget onPressedCommentButton(context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.4,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 12,
                                            bottom: 12,
                                            left: 10),
                                        child: Container(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.8,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "content",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 17,
                                                color: Colors.white
                                                    .withOpacity(0.9)),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            right: 10, left: 10),
                                        child: Container(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.1,
                                          child: Text(
                                            "date",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 13,
                                                color: Colors.grey),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )),
                              Divider(
                                thickness: 0,
                                height: 5,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),),
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 6, bottom: 6, left: 10, right: 5),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _addComment,
                    maxLines: 4,
                    minLines: 1,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    maxLength: 150,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                      counterText: "",
                      hintText: "Yorum ekleyiniz...",
                      hintStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
                      suffixIcon: Container(
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            FocusScope.of(context)
                                .requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                            newComment();
                          },
                          child: Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.paperPlane,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      });
}
```

Normally there is a lot of backend integration in the code, but in order not to confuse you, I deleted them and shared the code here. My only aim is to get the textfield on the keyboard. 
Thanks to everyone who helped in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'I can't get it over the keyboard'? Okay, from what I can understand, *showModalBottomSheet* works when you only have the *textField* in it, but when you also add the *Container* widget, the *showModalBottomSheet* is not functioning properly? And exactly not functioning how? (Just a blank screen or...?)

Comment: @Unbreachable
Previously, I was using only one text field in the showModalBottomSheet, and then the textfield hovered over the keyboard. But later, when I added a container over this textfield, the textfield did not come over the keyboard.
I want to put both the container and the textfield on the keyboard right now.

Comment: Okay I see, remove the `SingleChildScrollView` and the `height` and `width` properties from the first `Container` widget. That should probably work.

Comment: @Unbreachable I removed showModalBottomSheet and I type showBottomSheet. It's worked :) Thank you for helps